# Upon upgrading Android Studio, a particular project of mines cant seem to run. I get an error saying this The project is not a graddle based project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

Additionally, In the event log, I also get errors which say "could not read ok from ADB server", "failed to start daemon", "error cant connect to daemon","C:\Users\pilla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary".

The project is a flutter based project and used to run before I updated Android studio. I tried uninstalling Android studio, deleting all related files, and performing a fresh install as well as looking at similar project sync related issues but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any idea how I can get this project up and running again?

Comment: Do you have flutter installed? and the Flutter and Dart plugin in Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, both flutter and the dart plugin are installed